# Getting error while Spring Boot application start up using gradle dependency

Tags: gradle, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Getting This error please help me out

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1566)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:961)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:950)
        at com.omneagate.rest.RestApplication.main(RestApplication.java:223)
    Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:104)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:71)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:205)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1887)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1845)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:852)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:845)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:398)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:844)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1625)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1562)
        ... 15 more
```

---

My application.properties file

```
# datasource properties
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pds_00038_11092015
spring.datasource.username=dev
spring.datasource.password=dev123
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.testOnBorrow=true
spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.region.factory_class=org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory
security.headers.cache=false
security.sessions=stateless
server.port=9094
#security.basic.enabled=false

# rabbit mqueue configurations
spring.rabbitmq.host=localhost
spring.rabbitmq.username=debendrap
spring.rabbitmq.password=debendrap
spring.rabbitmq.virtual-host=debendrap
queue.name=deb1
queue.concurrentuser=100
queue.maxconcurrent.user=512

# rabbit mqueue configurations
smstask.queue.name=pdssmstask
smstask.queue.concurrentuser=30
smstask.queue.maxconcurrent.user=100

# application configurations
stringdigester.iteration.count=1000
stringdigester.poolsize.count=16
stringdigester.saltsize=10

threadexecutor.core.poolsize=50
threadexecutor.max.poolsize=500
threadexecutor.queue.capacity=250

#sms expiry time
sms.expirytime=180 

#except sms url please do not change other properties
#sms service url
sms.service.url=http://localhost:8880/pdsmessagingwebservice/smsrequest/sendsms

#sms service username
sms.service.username=pd$smsuser

#sms service password
sms.service.password=p@$$word!

#bill item details in txn
txn.billitem.msg=%s(%s)Rs%s;

#****** Otp related properties *******#
#otp length
otp.length=7

#sms expiry time
#In seconds. Used for transactions
otp.expirytime=180

#sms expiry time
#In seconds. Used for activation
otp.activationreq.expiry=10080  

#****** Otp related properties*******#
#Do not change the algorithm
encryption.algorithm=PBEWITHSHA-256AND256BITAES-CBC-BC

ldap.service.url=http://localhost:9060/peopleldap/authenticate

#Open LDAP configuration
ldap.url=ldap://localhost
ldap.base=dc=cscpd,dc=in
ldap.user=cn=admin,dc=cscpd,dc=in
ldap.password=cscpdpds

#******* Elcot db compare service ****#
# possible values true or false
elcotdb.compareservice.enable=false
# Only number allowed
elcotdb.fixedthreadpool.size=10

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
my RestApplication.java file

package com.omneagate.rest;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.jasypt.digest.PooledStringDigester;
import org.jasypt.digest.StringDigester;
import org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.Queue;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter;
import org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.Jackson2JsonMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessageConverter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate;
import org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
import org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import com.omneagate.rest.elcotcompare.ElcotCompareTask;
import com.omneagate.rest.security.FpsFilter;
import com.omneagate.rest.service.SmsTaskListener;
import com.omneagate.utilities.LdapTreeBuilder;

@Configuration  
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ImportResource("classpath:security.xml" )
@EnableScheduling
// This class is the entry point of the application.
public class RestApplication {
    @Value("${queue.name}")
    String queueName;

    @Value("${queue.concurrentuser}")
    int concurrentUsers;

    @Value("${queue.maxconcurrent.user}")
    int maxConcurrentUsers;

    /** String digester properties */
    @Value("${stringdigester.poolsize.count}")
    int stringDigesterPoolSize;

    @Value("${stringdigester.iteration.count}")
    int stringDigesterIterations;

    @Value("${stringdigester.saltsize}")
    int stringDigesterSaltSize;

    /** Thread executor properties */
    @Value("${threadexecutor.core.poolsize}")
    int threadExecutorCoreSize;

    @Value("${threadexecutor.max.poolsize}")
    int threadPoolMaxSize;

    @Value("${threadexecutor.queue.capacity}")
    int threadPoolQueueCapacity;

    /** SMS Task queue configuration */
    @Value("${smstask.queue.name}")
    String smsTaskqueue;

    @Value("${smstask.queue.concurrentuser}")
    int smsTaskConcurrentUsers;

    @Value("${queue.maxconcurrent.user}")
    int smsTaskMaxConcurrentUser;

    @Bean
    MessageConverter messageConverter() {
        return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    }

    @Bean
    RabbitTemplate template(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
            MessageConverter converter) {
        RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
        template.setMessageConverter(converter);
        return template;
    }

    @Bean
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container(
            ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
            MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter) {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(
                connectionFactory);
        container.setQueueNames(queueName);
        container.setConcurrentConsumers(concurrentUsers);
        container.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(maxConcurrentUsers);
        container.setMessageListener(listenerAdapter);
        //container.setTaskExecutor(getAsyncExecutor());
        return container;
    }

    @Bean
    SmsTaskListener smsTaskListener(){
        return new SmsTaskListener();
    }

    @Bean
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer smsTaskContainer(
            ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,MessageConverter converter) {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(
                connectionFactory);
        container.setQueueNames(smsTaskqueue);
        container.setConcurrentConsumers(smsTaskConcurrentUsers);
        container.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(smsTaskMaxConcurrentUser);
        container.setMessageListener(new MessageListenerAdapter(smsTaskListener(),converter));
        //container.setTaskExecutor(getAsyncExecutor());
        return container;
    }

    @Bean
    StringDigester PasswordHash() {
        final PooledStringDigester stringDigester = new PooledStringDigester();
        stringDigester.setAlgorithm("SHA-256");
        stringDigester.setIterations(stringDigesterIterations);
        stringDigester.setSaltSizeBytes(stringDigesterSaltSize);
        stringDigester.setPoolSize(stringDigesterPoolSize);
        stringDigester.initialize();
        return stringDigester; 
    }

    @Bean
    MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter(
            com.omneagate.rest.service.Listener listener,
            MessageConverter converter) {
        return new MessageListenerAdapter(listener, converter);
    }

    @Bean(name="threadexecutor")
    public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor getAsyncExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
            executor.setCorePoolSize(threadExecutorCoreSize);
            executor.setMaxPoolSize(threadPoolMaxSize);
            executor.setQueueCapacity(threadPoolQueueCapacity);
            executor.initialize();
            return executor;
    }

    @Bean
    Queue queue() {
        return new Queue(queueName, true);
    }

    @Bean
    Queue smsTaskqueue() {
        return new Queue(smsTaskqueue, true);
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean authorizationFilter() {
        FilterRegistrationBean filterRegBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        filterRegBean.setFilter(new FpsFilter());
        List<String> urlPatterns = new ArrayList<String>();
        urlPatterns.add("/*");
        filterRegBean.setUrlPatterns(urlPatterns);
        return filterRegBean;
    }

    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    @Bean
    public LdapContextSource contextSource () {
        LdapContextSource contextSource= new LdapContextSource();
        contextSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty("ldap.url"));
        contextSource.setBase(env.getRequiredProperty("ldap.base"));
        contextSource.setUserDn(env.getRequiredProperty("ldap.user"));
        contextSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty("ldap.password"));
        return contextSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LdapTreeBuilder ldapTreeBuilder(){
        return new LdapTreeBuilder(ldapTemplate());
    }

    @Bean
    public LdapTemplate ldapTemplate() {
        return new LdapTemplate(contextSource());        
    }

    @Bean
    public StandardPBEStringEncryptor getEncryptor() {
        return new StandardPBEStringEncryptor();        
    }

    @Bean
    public BouncyCastleProvider getCipherProvider() {
        return new BouncyCastleProvider();        
    }

    @Bean   
    public ElcotCompareTask elcotCompareTask() {
        return new ElcotCompareTask();        
    }

    public void scheduleElcotCompare(){
        new ElcotCompareTask();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RestApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try setting this property in your application.properties file:

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

(With the right dialect depending on your database of course)

JPA needs it to be able to generate the correct code to interact with your database.

If it doesn't help, please provide more information about your application. Are you overriding any of spring-boot's auto configuration? What dependencies are you using in your gradle file? Did you include spring-boot-starter-data-jpa AND a database connector?

Comment: @DebendraParida Consider marking my answer as the right answer if it helped solving your problem.